# How can I use vector for entering numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I want to enter names, student numbers and student scores and display this information. 
I used arrays in this way:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define size 3
using namespace std;
class student{
public:
    void vrod();
    void dis();
    int stno,score,i,n;
};
void student::vrod(){
cout<<"name=";
cin>>name;
cout<<"stno=";
cin>>stno;
cout<<"score=";
cin>>score;
}
void student::dis(){
    cout<<"name="<<name<<"\n"<<"stno="<<stno<<"\n"<<"score="<<score<<"\n";

}


int main(){
int i, j=0,n,;
string h;

student st[size];
while (j<3){
st[j].vrod();

j++;}
j=0;
while (j<3){
st[j].dis();

j++;}
cin.get();
cin.get();
}
```

According to recommendation of my friends, I used vector in this way:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#define n 3
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int input;
  string names;
  vector<int> stno,score;
  vector<string> name;
  cout<<"Enter the number of inputs: ";

  cout << "Enter your numbers to be evaluated: " << endl;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      cout<<"student No.=";
  cin >> input;
  stno.push_back(input);
  }

 for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
      cout<<"scor=";
  cin >> input;
  score.push_back(input);
  }

 for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
     cout<<"name=";
  cin >> names;
  name.push_back(names);
  }

   for(int i=0;i<stno.size();i++)
       cout<<stno[i];
    for(int i=0;i<score.size();i++)
       cout<<score[i];
    for(int i=0;i<name.size();i++)
       cout<<name[i];

  cin.get();
  cin.get();
}
```

Do you have any opinion to improve the second code written via vector? Can I save information from one student including student numbers and student scores in one position in vector like arrays? I mean for example if my n is 3, I enter the information of students in three positions like arrays(student st[size];)

Comment: Maybe you need to visit [**Code Review**](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a code review site. You may be able to ask the question on codereview.stackexchange.com , but please first read their help pages about what questions are on-topic and also on how to write a good question.

Comment: He/She is asking if a vector can be accessed/set like an array, I think. It may need to be reworded a little bit.

Comment: @Taztingo They ask *"Do you have any opinion to improve ... ?"* and that is code review. They ask *"Can I save .. ? I mean ..."* and that is unclear what they are asking. They give a large amount of badly formatted code which is not a [mcve].

Comment: @AdrianHHH "It may need to be reworded a little bit."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I save information from one student including student numbers and
>   student scores in one position in vector like arrays? I mean for
>   example if my n is 3, I enter the information of students in three
>   positions like arrays(student st[size];)

Yes you can. A std::vector is a dynamic array that expands. So you could do something like this...

```
    std::vector<student> my_vector;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        student new_student;

        cout << "Number: "
        cin >> new_student.number;
        cout << "Score: "
        cin >> new_student.score;
        cout << "Name: "
        cin >> new_student.name;

        my_vector.push_back(new_student);
    }

    //Accessing
    std::cout << "Hello my name is: " + my_vector[0].name;

   //Setting
   vector[0].name = "Cranky Kong";
   std::cout << "Hello my name is: " + my_vector[0].name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. As I read tutorial , it is common to use std:: vector<int> my_vector. why do not you use <int>? What is the duty of student new_student? it is not available in tutorial.:)

Comment: Yes sorry, you want. std::vector<student>. new_student is a student object that is being put inside the vector. This is a part of the Standard Template Library (STL). In a nutshell it means that the vector object will only contain a user specified type. In this case I am saying yo vector you will contain objects of type student. "std::vector<student>". If you wanted to create a vector of int you say yo vector you will contain objects of type int. "std::vector<int>"

Comment: Again thanks, How about student new_student;? I wrote that code,but ti is written identifier student undefined and variable new_student is not a type name. What is the problem with?  Thanks,

Comment: I am creating an object there of type student. In your code you posted you had `class student{
public:
    void vrod();
    void dis();
    int stno,score,i,n;
};`

So I'm creating an object of type student, and naming it new_student.

Comment: OK. I got. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, accept this as the answer if it solved everything for you.